# If $E(X^-)=0$ then $P(X\geqslant0)=1$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Let $I(t)$ a real-valued stochastic process with continuous trajectories.
Let $I^-(t)$ the negative part of $I(t)$, so $I(t)=I^+(t)-I^-(t)$.
I know that $\mathbb{E}[I^-(t)]=0$, and I have to prove that $\mathbb{P}(I(t) \ge0)=1$.

I tried to argue by absurd to prove $\mathbb{P}(I(t) <0)=0$ but I'm not able to reach a contraddiction.

Comment: In general, if $X$ is non-negative and $\mathrm{E}[X]=0$, then $X=0$ almost surely.

Comment: @StefanHansen ok, I know it. But I don't understend how can I conclude with your observation.

Comment: This gives you that $I^{-}(t)=0$ almost surely and hence...

Comment: @StefanHansen If I'm asking a question is because I don't know the answer. Please, I need to understand and not to answer to a quiz. If you want to help be more clear.

Comment: And I'm giving you hints to try and involve you in the process thinking you might learn something.